# Split a delimited string column in data frame, take only last element in new column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

This has to be an incredibly easy task (and yeah this will probably be marked as a duplicate) but I can't find ANYWHERE how to do this simply within a dataframe without creating lists from the columns and putting them back. Reproducible code below:

I simply wish to separate the last element in the column df, delimited by comma:

```
df<- c("Lagos, Nigeria", "United States", "Buckingham Palace, Great Britain", 
   "Madison Square Garden, NY, New York, USA")
df <- data.frame(df, c(1:length(df)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$column.desired <- c("Nigeria", "United States", "Great Britain", 
              "USA")
```

Comment: From the marked duplicate, `sub('.*\\,', '', df$df)` should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `sub` to match characters (`.*`) until a comma `,` followed by zero or more space (`\\s*`), followed by one or more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]+`) until the end (`$`) of the string, capture as a group (`(...)`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df$column.desired <-sub(".*,\\s*([^,]+)$", "\\1", df$df)
df$column.desired
#[1] "Nigeria"       "United States" "Great Britain" "USA"
```

Comment: I knew this was easy, but it was driving me crazy. Thanks! Cheers.

Comment: `gsub(".*?,\\s","",df$df)` is the best way I could think of The output being
`[1] "Nigeria"       "United States" "Great Britain" "USA" `

Comment: Actually, I realized there is no need of the`?`